# How do I make a section required for a sectiongroup in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I want to make a section inside of a sectiongroup required for that section group but not required for the entire install if the group is unchecked. I've tried "SectionIn R0" but this makes that section required for the entire install and I only want it to be required if they select the group itself.

```
SectionGroup "group"
  Section "required for section group"
    SectionIn RO
  SectionEnd

  Section "optional"
  SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with just properties, you need some actual code:

```
!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

SectionGroup /e "group"
  Section "required for section group" SEC_REQ
    SectionIn RO
  SectionEnd
  Section "optional" SEC_OPT
  SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

Function .onSelChange
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_OPT}
    !define /math MYSECTIONFLAGS ${SF_SELECTED} | ${SF_RO}
    !insertmacro SetSectionFlag ${SEC_REQ} ${MYSECTIONFLAGS} 
    !undef MYSECTIONFLAGS
${Else}
    !insertmacro ClearSectionFlag ${SEC_REQ} ${SF_RO}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Note that there is a "bug" when unchecking the section group itself, to workaround that, you need to keep some global state since nsis does not tell you which section generated the notification. The following code has better logic:

```
!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

SectionGroup /e "group" SEC_GRP
  Section "required for section group" SEC_REQ
    SectionIn RO
  SectionEnd
  Section "optional" SEC_OPT
  SectionEnd
  Section "" PRIVSEC_TOGGLESTATE ;hidden section to keep track of state
  SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

Function .onSelChange
!define /math SECFLAGS_SELRO ${SF_SELECTED} | ${SF_RO}
${IfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${PRIVSEC_TOGGLESTATE}
${AndIf} ${SectionIsReadOnly} ${SEC_REQ}
    !insertmacro ClearSectionFlag ${SEC_REQ} ${SECFLAGS_SELRO}
${EndIf}
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_OPT}
    !insertmacro SetSectionFlag ${SEC_REQ} ${SECFLAGS_SELRO} 
${Else}
    !insertmacro ClearSectionFlag ${SEC_REQ} ${SF_RO}
${EndIf}
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_REQ}
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${PRIVSEC_TOGGLESTATE}
${Else}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${PRIVSEC_TOGGLESTATE}
${EndIf}
!undef SECFLAGS_SELRO
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the sections as mandatory sections by using the SectionSetFlags command. You simply need to add it to the .onInit function as follows:

```
SectionGroup "group" Sec01
  Section "required for section group"
  SectionIn RO
  SectionEnd

  Section "optional" Sec02
  SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

Function .onInit
  SectionSetFlags ${Sec01} 17
FunctionEnd
```

This will gray "group" out, but it will be selected and installed as expected.

Comment: Much simpler than the accepted answer. However, I think it's a mistake that you have "Sec01" twice.

Comment: Well spotted - I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup a custom function which is being called when user clicks "Next" but no option is selected. In this function, you can check if any of Sections is selected or, as I did, check the variable which is set to "nothingSelected" on init, then modified when any section is created. If you put "Abort" in the custom function, the installer will stay on the same page. Here is a snippet:

```
page license
page directory
page components "" "" testSelection
page instfiles

function .onInit
    StrCpy $somethingSelected "nothingSelected"
functionEnd

function testSelection
    ${If} $somethingSelected == "nothingSelected"
        MessageBox MB_OK "Please select any option" 
        Abort
     ${EndIf}
functionEnd


function .onSelChange
    #selecting mutually exclusive sections (removed for clarity)
    StrCpy $somethingSelected $1
functionEnd
```